# Abrir una activity desde un fragmento con un botón en kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, botón, activity

Soy nuevo en desarrollo de apps y tengo un problema que no puedo resolver desde hace ya 4 días. Estoy haciendo una app con bottom navigation y en uno de los fragmentos quiero colocar varios botones que redirijan a varias Activity. El problema esta que cuando enciendo la app todo va correcto hasta que me meto en la opcion del fragment donde tengo los botones y entonces la app se cierra. Aquí dejo el código a mi fragment:
class TeoriaFragment : Fragment() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teoria, container, false)
    val boton3 = button3


    view.boton3.setOnclickListener{
        view.context.startActivity(Intent(view.context,SimpleActivity::class))
    }

    return view
}
```

y aquí dejo el código a mi activity:

class MainActivity3 : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
private val teoriaFragment = TeoriaFragment()
private val practicaFragment = PracticaFragment()



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)
    replaceFragment(homeFragment)

    bottom_navigation.setOnItemSelectedListener{
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.navigation_home -> replaceFragment(homeFragment)
            R.id.navigation_teoria -> replaceFragment(teoriaFragment)
            R.id.navigation_practica -> replaceFragment(practicaFragment)
        }
        true
    }


}


private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
    if(fragment !=null){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }
```

De antemano, muchas gracias
edit:
estos son los errores que me aparecen en el logcat

Unresolved reference: boton3

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent

Comment: Estaría bien que mires el `logcat` o la sección de debug en Android Studio para saber qué error se produce y lo incluyas en la pregunta

Comment: Unresolved reference: boton3
e: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error:

> Unresolved reference: boton3

indica que no se encuentra la referencia de la vista "boton3", debes asegurar que dentro del archivo `fragment_teoria.xml` se encuentre en verdad el botón con id `button3`, para poder obtener su referencia de esta forma:

```
...
...
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teoria, container, false)
     //  val boton3 = button3
     val boton3 = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.boton3) as Button
...
...
```

después de obtener la referencia del botón ya puedes asignarle el clicklistener para poder abrir la Activity.

El contexto que debes usar sería el de la activity que contiene el fragmento, lo obtienes mediante `activity`.

Por lo tanto este sería el código:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    //Infla layout
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teoria, container, false)
    //Obtiene referencia de botón.
    val boton3 = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.boton3) as Button

    //Asigna listener para poder abrir Activity.
    boton3.setOnClickListener{ view: View ->
            val intent = Intent (activity , SimpleActivity::class.java)
            activity?.startActivity(intent)
    }

    return view
}
```